# Javascript Dictionary keys are undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a dictionary of data for each state, but when I do this it says that mapData["Alabama"] is undefined and that the object has no keys. When I print it to the console it prints out as an object with each state as a key.

```
   let mapData = {};
    d3.csv("./resources/states/us_2016_states.csv" , function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(d){
            mapData[d.State] = {"score": 0, "count":0, "state": d.State}

        })
    })
    console.log(Object.keys(mapData))
    console.log(mapData["Alabama"])
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the console shows a live reference of the object.

Comment: ya. the console logs into the csv callback and see if that fixes it. Just move the  last "})" below the console.logs

Comment: If I simply print out mapData it shows it as an object with keys, but when to access the keys, it says they are undefined

Comment: Again, that happens because the object in the console is a live reference.